# Help trimming string input of it's return character MIPS

Tags: string, mips

I'm writing a game in MIPS and I take in a player's name. When I try to print something like:

```
li $v0, 4  
la $a0, playerName  
syscall

li $v0, 4  
la $a0, strEnd     #strEnd = ("'s Hand: ")  
syscall
```

So I want it to display:

```
"playerName's Hand: "
```

Everything doesn't appear on the same line. I instead get:

```
"playerName  
's Hand: "
```

My question is how can I strip the new line character from the name I took in? Thanks

Comment: Wow, a game in MIPS, masochism at its finest

Answer (score 2):

```
# Your code to take a player's name

    li $s0,0               # Set index to 0
remove:
    lb $a3,word($s0)      # Load character at index
    addi $s0,$s0,1        # Increment index
    bnez $a3,remove    # Loop until the end of string is reached
    beq $a1,$s0,skip      # Do not remove \n when it isn't present
    subiu $s0,$s0,2     # Backtrack index to '\n'
    sb $0, word($s0)        # Add the terminating character in its place
```

Removes the newLine character :)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the string containing the player name, until you reach the null character. Store that position. Then place a null character at pos-1. (I think you'll have to put it at pos-2 as well, since a newline is sometimes 2 separate characters.)